# what is the padding value formula wrt kernel size and stride in tensorflow when it is "same"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is there any universal formula that tensorflow follows while decoding the "same" value wrt the kernel size and stride

`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(hiddim_v * 4, kernel_size = 3, stride= 1, "same")`

Answer (score 0):

As per official documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution

```
If padding == "SAME": output_spatial_shape[i] = ceil(input_spatial_shape[i] / strides[i])
If padding == "VALID": output_spatial_shape[i] = ceil((input_spatial_shape[i] - (spatial_filter_shape[i]-1) * dilation_rate[i]) / strides[i]).
```

spatial_filter_shape is kernel size

Comment: that's not my doubt. I want to rather know what is the padding value formula... You have mentioned...what would be the output widht and height.. but rather i wanna know how many numbers do they pad....using tf.pad([0,pw,ph,0])

Is there any universal formula for finding pw and ph?

thanks

Comment: I doubt that tf.pad is used explicitly, since conv op only has two options. I think it just computes output shape. You can find more info in nn_ops.py file.